# Cross check BCRYPT

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

I want to know if it is possible to cross check bcrypt with random salts in a database. I want to actually make a function that allows an admin to see the hash of the password, as well as cross check them in the database to check if they have other accounts. I've done this with IP-adresses, browsers and session ids, but I want to cross check the accounts passwords too. If I was using sha1 or md5 I could've done it, but I am not going to make the passwords any easier for the attacker to guess/hack.

So.. is it possible to cross check/reference bcrypt passwords with salts? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: How would you "check if they have other accounts" based on a password hash?  I think you need to describe what you're trying to accomplish in better detail.

Comment: I want an admin function to cross check user accounts with IP, browser and session ids as well as login time.. I've done the things I mentioned here, but I would really like to cross reference the password hash as well. With this function, it would be pretty easy for admins to check if a player has multiple accounts or not. But like I said, it's hard to to with bcrypt and a random salt.

Comment: If you're talking about checking for multiple accounts that have the same password, then that's impossible if you're salting correctly (using a different random salt for each account).  What you're doing in general seems very sketchy, as well.  IPs can be the same across hundreds or thousands of users.  Browser details (like user agent) can change on every request; or even be empty.  Session ID should never be duplicated across user accounts in an application that does sessions right, since it would be regenerated on login.  So... I would advise giving up on this endeavor.